# Load JAGS to cluster

Tags: hpc, jags, r2jags

I would like to install jagsUI on the cluster that I am using. However, this requires me to load JAGS4.3.0 module which I have installed on my computer. This is the error I get when installing jagsUI:

```
During startup - Warning message:
Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
* installing *source* package 'rjags' ...
** package 'rjags' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using non-staged installation
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
configure: WARNING: pkg-config file for jags 4 unavailable
configure: WARNING: Consider adding the directory containing `jags.pc`
configure: WARNING: to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
configure: Attempting legacy configuration of rjags
checking for jags... no
configure: error: "automatic detection of JAGS failed. Please use pkg-config to locate the JAGS library. See the INSTALL file for details."
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'rjags'
* removing '/home/cltane002/Rlibs/rjags'
During startup - Warning message:
Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
ERROR: dependency 'rjags' is not available for package 'jagsUI'
* removing '/home/cltane002/Rlibs/jagsUI'

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/RtmpyIUv3r/downloaded_packages'
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("jagsUI", "~/Rlibs", "http://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN") :
  installation of package 'rjags' had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("jagsUI", "~/Rlibs", "http://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN") :
  installation of package 'jagsUI' had non-zero exit status
```

I have checked on my terminal whether jags has been installed. The module file for jags is not showing when I do module in the terminal connected to the cluster.  I do I load the JAGS software to the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

I would check the documentation page of the hpc cluster. The cluster I used before from my university have already compiled and installed the JAGS module on the cluster. All I needed to do is simply load the module. Usually, the hpc documentation website has a page on what modules are available and also example scripts to load and run them.